# System administration skills for data engineering

Tags: data, databases

As a data scientist student, I will do an internship with a lot of data engineering tasks.

It would be good if I had some initiation skills in sys-admins.

This leads me to my questions:

- Why should I have skills in sys-admins?
- What introduction course would you suggest to me? (I know that their data are on AWS)

Thanks a lot !!